# Cannot read property 'getContext' of null is driving me crazy

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I'm following a video tutorial of YouTube, and replicating it on jsfiddle, codepen and directly on my coder brackets and I'm getting the same error all the time:

Cannot read property 'getContext' why? can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I thought could be the image path, I've tried with an image src directly from a folder ./images/image1.jpg and I've tried with a web link address to an img. None of them work.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 400;

const image1 = new Image();
image1.src = 'https://reason.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/guybentley.jpg';
image1.addEventListener('load', function(){
  ctx.drawImage(image1, 0,0);
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color:black;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#canvas1 {
  border:solid 3px white;
  width:800px;
  height:400px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
   <div id="canvas1"></div>
```

Comment: <div>s don't have a context, only <canvas> does

Comment: `<div id="canvas1"></div>` is not a canvas element, are you looking for something like: `<canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="100"></canvas>`

Comment: omg thanks @dandavis this is why I've been fighting stupidly for 1 hour. thanks a lot for clarifying my mind, this won't happen again that's for sure hahah

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext

Answer (score 4):

- Instead of `<div>` use `<canvas>`:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 400;

const image1 = new Image();
image1.src = 'https://reason.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/guybentley.jpg';
image1.addEventListener('load', function(){
  ctx.drawImage(image1, 0,0);
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color:black;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#canvas1 {
  border:solid 3px white;
  width:800px;
  height:400px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
   <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```